# Help creating minecraft server at bootup

Tags: boot, server, permissions, java, minecraft

I followed this tutorial here: [How to I make a program start on boot (no gui)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198585/how-to-i-make-a-program-start-on-boot-no-gui)

I get the following error message once I run systemctl start minecraft:

```
systemd[6640]: minecraft.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: Permission denied
systemd[6742]: minecraft.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning java: Permission denied
```

I am new to linux and am trying to understand how user and group permissions work.

My minecraft.service file is as follows:

```
[Unit]
Description=Minecraft server
Wants=network.target                                                    #Runs after network is up
After=local-fs.target network.target

[Service]
User=minecraft
Group=minecraft
UMask=0027

EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/minecraft
KillMode=none
SuccessExitStatus=0 1 255

NoNewPrivileges=true
PrivateDevices=true
PrivateTmp=true
ProtectHome=true
ProtectSystem=full

WorkingDirectory=/home/minecraft
ExecStart=java -Xms${MINHEAP} -Xmx${MAXHEAP} -XX:ParallelGCThreads=${THREADS} -jar server.jar --nogui
# ExecStop=/usr/bin/mcrcon -H localhost -p ${RCON_PASSWD} stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```